# How do I set timeout for LocalNotification

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, localnotification

How do I set timeout like example I want the notification to be

1. Trigger start from (27 Nov 2020, 12pm)
2. Subsequently every one hour until 28 Nov 2020, 12pm.

Without reopening the app, heres my codes.

```
 var mySchedule: LocalNotificationSchedule = {
      on:"27 Nov 2020, 12pm",
      repeats: true,
      every: 'hour',
      count:1,
      #until : "28 Nov 2020, 12pm"
    };
    var notification={};
    notification["title"]="Local Notification Test";
    notification["body"]="Example body";
    notification["id"]="2";
    notification["schedule"]=mySchedule;
    notification["sound"]="default";
    this.localNoti.push(notification);
    const notifs = await LocalNotifications.schedule({
      notifications:  this.localNoti
    });
```

Comment: Not sure if this could work but there are 24 hours between 27 Nov 2020 12pm and 28 Nov 2020 12 pm so instead of `count: 1` what happens if you set `count: 24`?

Comment: Thanks will try it.